# Adding elements to an ArrayList in the correct position

Tags: java, arraylist, compareto

I need to create an add method which will add items from a txt file to an array list and at the same time sort them alphabetically (homework). I have created some code but keep getting a null pointer exception error.

```
public void add(String str)
{   

  int index = 0; 
  str = list[index];
  String str2 = list[index+1]; 
  int result = str.compareTo(str2);

  for(index=0; index < elements; index++){

      if(result < 0){
         list[index] = str2;
      }

      else if (result > 0){
         list[index] = str;
      }
```

Here's the main method code which the error is coming from

```
for (int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_NAMES;i++)
  al.add(names[i]);
```

Comment: Show your entire main method please.

Comment: Are you supposed to be using an array `String[]` or `ArrayList<String>`?

Comment: Why not just add it to the Array or ArrayList, and right after adding, sort it using `Collections.sort` or `Arrays.sort`?

Comment: use 'TreeSet' if won't get duplicates

Comment: Why pass a `String` if you are just going to immediately overwrite it?

Comment: Also, you may want to read up on Insertion Sort. This seems right for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

your main method :

```
List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_NAMES;i++){
        l = addItem(names[i], l);
    }
```

add method:

```
public static List<String> addItem(String item, List<String> list) {

        list.add(item);

        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String s1, String s2) {
                return s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);
            }
        });

        return list;
    }
```